# Correct naming for my UIImage with JPG

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have just got a mail that my application has passed the review and is available in the App Store now. However the background images do not show up.

Before I used .png, but since they obtain lots of memory compared to .jpg, I converted the images to .jpg. (It saved around 40 MB.)

So like the .png, I dragged the .jpg to the Images.xcassets and tried on the simulator. This worked, also if I loaded it on my Iphone through the simulator.
I was looking to my code if anything was wrong, to be certain.

---

Every screen is calling this method:

```
//Background image
UIImageView *backgroundView = [MyManager grabImage:FALSE];
backgroundView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
```

The method grabImage looks as following:

```
+(UIImageView *)grabImage:(BOOL)main{
    UIImageView *Image;
    if(main){
        Image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background1.png"]];
    }else{
        Image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background2.png"]];
    }
}
```

So I spotted the Obvious error. It still had the .png. However before I send the App and wait more than a week again, I want to be certain how to call it.

Should I use Background1 or Background1.jpg?

> I have read on another StackOverflow topic that with .jpg, you should
>   Always use the extension. I do not see the logic to have
>   Background1.jpg though. Since my casset is called Background1 but, files are called like; Background1
>   2x.jpg, Background1 ipad 2x.jpg etc.

@Edit 13:23 - 14-01-2016
I tried to rename my Images in the xcassets. From Background1 to BackgroundMain and when calling `imageNamed:@"BackgroundMain"`. It did not show up anymore, and gave the default backgroundcolor. When using `imageNamed:@"BackgroundMain.jpg"`it did show up.

My conclusion is that the prior naming is somehow kept in memory/cache. The .jpg extension is a must though! (I'll leave the question here in case anyone runs into the same problem. (Since it saves a lot of time with resending the package)

Comment: Note that iPhone applies PNG compression optimizations when you copy the image to the device. Make sure you're comparing actual sizes on the device, not in the simulator (this can be a bit tricky to do; you may have to walk through your own files with `NSFileManager`). The device also is optimized to load and display PNGs. Don't assume that JPEG is giving you a big benefit if you haven't checked it on device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image names in Images.xcassets should usually be referenced without the extension, this works for PNGs, but apparently causes issues with other file types. My testing shows that the extension doesn't matter on the simulator, but you're finding that this isn't true in the app store. In that case leave on the .jpg extension as that appears to be working correctly for you.

I think the topic you are referring to is about when you add images directly to your project, in that case you can omit the extension if it is .png, but must include it for other files types.

Comment: Okay, Thank you! Can you also explain why it did work on my phone, through the simulator (Even with the .png extensions)?

Comment: I've just tested this, and I think it must strip the extensions. I can load the same png image using [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgName.png"] and [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgName.jpg"], they both display correctly.

Comment: But if it strips extensions, than it should refer to Background1 image cassets, which has all the .jpg now instead of .png and does not work. (It does via simulator, but not via the appstore)

Comment: Check the contents.json file and make sure they are referencing the correct files. Also make sure you clean your build before retrying otherwise the old images will remain. If you have it working with .jpg, i'd leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the method you use looks for a file, not an asset. The official documentation ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed: ) states the following :

> The name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle.

I always use full file name but the method is smart enough to call the right image since suffixes like "@2x" does not need to be in the name you call to eventualy use the right image (like using @2x when on retina display).

Comment: It does also say _'loads the image data from disk or asset catalog'_

Answer (score 1):

When you add an image to the asset catalog you have two things...

1. the image file name
2. the catalog "group" name

From what you say you have changed the file name to "backgroundMain" and then expected `[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundMain"]];` to work but in this case it will be looking for a `png` called `backgroundMain.png` (as per the docs).

Because you have changed the image file name the asset group name is unchanged.

What you want to do all the time regardless of whether an image is jpg or png or gif etc... Is to use the Asset catalog group name.

This will then return the correct image based on the resolution of the device and the files (all with different names) inside the group.

For example... You can have an asset called "Background" and inside have a standard (@1x) image called "Fred.png" an @2x image called "Barney.jpg" and an @3x image called "Wilma.gif".

By using the code `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"];` it will load the correct image for standard, retina and retinaHD screens regardless of the file name of the image.

Comment: I believe the confusion is coming from the fact that in your example [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]; will load the correct asset, regardless of the backing file name or format.

Comment: @JamesP ah, I see now. Thanks :D